# Javascript building a treeView with object

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, treeview

I started working with Javascript and Jquery couple of weeks ago. Now at the office I have to build a Object that contain Child and grandChild and etc..

I know the best way would be to perform a recursive function but can't figure it out. I have been able to work but as soon as i Have 2 level I fail...

I have this data :

```
dataTest = [
        { que_code: "BM1", que_enonce: "Test 1", que_id: "1", que_id_parent: null },
        { que_code: "BM2", que_enonce: "Test 2", que_id: "2", que_id_parent: 1 },
        { que_code: "BM3", que_enonce: "Test 3", que_id: "3", que_id_parent: 1 },
        { que_code: "BM4", que_enonce: "Test 4", que_id: "4", que_id_parent: null },
        { que_code: "BM5", que_enonce: "Test 5", que_id: "5", que_id_parent: 3 },
    ];
```

I result should give the following

- BM1

  - BM2
  - BM3

    - BM5
- BM4

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this, you can first use recursion to create that tree data structure with `reduce()` method and then you can create another recursive function that will build HTML from that new data structure.

```js
var dataTest = [
  { que_code: "BM1", que_enonce: "Test 1", que_id: "1", que_id_parent: null },
  { que_code: "BM2", que_enonce: "Test 2", que_id: "2", que_id_parent: 1 },
  { que_code: "BM3", que_enonce: "Test 3", que_id: "3", que_id_parent: 1 },
  { que_code: "BM4", que_enonce: "Test 4", que_id: "4", que_id_parent: null },
  { que_code: "BM5", que_enonce: "Test 5", que_id: "5", que_id_parent: 3 },
];

function makeTree(data, parent = null) {
  return data.reduce(function(r, e) {
    if (e.que_id_parent == parent) {
      e.child = makeTree(data, e.que_id)
      r.push(e)
    }
    return r;
  }, [])
}

function toHtml(data, parent) {
  data.forEach(function(e) {
    var li = $('<li></li>')
    li.text(e.que_code)
    if (e.child.length) {
      var ul = $('<ul></ul>');
      ul.append(toHtml(e.child, ul));
    }
    li.append(ul)
    parent.append(li)
  })
}

var newData = makeTree(dataTest, null);
toHtml(newData, $('ul'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- DON'T FORGET THIS UL -->
<ul></ul>
```